# How to use custom certificate in corda

Tags: certificate, corda

We want to use codite in our corda app. is there any step by step implementation tutorail for this? Currently m checking on "https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/" but not much clear

Answer (score 1):

(Developer Relations @ R3 here)

The FAQ in their gitlab has some step by step instructions:
https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/blob/master/FAQ.md#1-show-me-how-to-set-up-a-simple-network and there's also a short tutorial in  https://medium.com/corda/cordite-network-map-69e5f2917c8a

Generally speaking we find that developing and testing apps is far easier on the Corda test network: https://testnet.corda.network though, could that work for you or do you have a specific use-case that makes cordite a requirement?